# Why does fit_transform always encode 'sex' as 0?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn

Why is my fit_transform not working?

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
# my stats
my_age=25
my_sex='male'  

# Creating a row with my stats  
my_dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[my_age, my_sex, 0]]),columns=['age', 'sex', 'sex_encoded'])  

print(my_dataset)    
my_dataset[['sex_encoded']]=OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(my_dataset[['sex']])       
print(my_dataset)
```

Here are the results:

```
  age   sex sex_encoded
0  25  male           0
  age   sex sex_encoded
0  25  male           0
```

For some reason OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform is not doing any transformation to 'sex'. I.e. no matter what I set my_sex to, the end result is always 0.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
my_age=25
my_sex='male'  

#Creating a row with my stats  
my_dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[my_age, my_sex, 0],[23, 'female', 0],[25, 'male', 0]]),columns=['age', 'sex', 'sex_encoded'])  
#print(my_dataset)

my_dataset['sex_encoded'] = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(my_dataset[['sex']])
print(my_dataset)
```